How to create horizontal stacked bar charts (sort of Gantt chart) multiple groups with line charts for each group in Chart.js?
Horizontal stacked bar charts with multiple groups
As for the horizontal stacked bar charts with multiple groups, I like this solution. It seems to work with chart.js@4.4.4 without any issues, so I’d like to use that version.
It looks like this (note the colours a generated, therefore every time one loads the chart, they are different):

Problem description
However, I am unable to modify it so that for each group I can add one or more line charts where the x axis is a timeline (just like it is for the bar charts) and y axis is a number in a unit (e.g. percentage). I want the height of each (sub-) chart (be it bar or line chart) to be same, therefore the y axis of a line chart should not have the same height as the whole chart (composed of all bar and line charts).
Bonus points
It would be awesome if I could define some thresholds to colour the either the line in line charts or some gradient below it, like when the value is:

> 90 %: green;
> 70 % and < 90 %: yellow;
< 70 %: red.

Nice to have
Show a vertical date line on hover. ;)

Why do you think that this questions should be closed? Should I add more code I tried to solve this problem? … This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. While I agree, but then half of SO questions should be closed. Moreover the chart.js tag has 1.1k watchrs and 12.4k questions ATM.
